# Can't get data from for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, request

Another problem... I have 2 functions :

```
function(data, callback){              //F1
            var URL = 'url';
            request(URL, function(err, response, body) {
                if(response.statusCode == 200){
                    var json = JSON.parse(body);
                    var chid = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < json['champions'].length;i++){
                        chid.push(json['champions'][i].id);
                    }
                    data.rotation = chid;
                    free = chid;
                    callback(null, data);
            }

        });
    },
function(data, callback) {        //f2
    for (var r=0; r<10; r++){
        var URL = 'url';
        request(URL,function(err, response, body) {
            if(response.statusCode == 200){
                var json = JSON.parse(body);

                x.push(json.name);
                data.rot = x;
            }   
        })
    }
    callback(null, data);
},
```

With F1 everything is ok. If I call `console.log(free)` or `console.log(data.rotation)` I got the array I want.

Function 2 is a bit problematic. Data is not avaible outside the for-loop. If I call `console.log(data.rot)` or `console.log(x)` outside the loop, it says it's undefined, so I can't get it with handlebars. I have no idea if it's all about the callback(null, data) position or about the for-loop. I can't handle it alone.

> How to get access to data outside of the for-loop, and how to fix this code?

Comment: You are making `asynchronous` requests in a loop and accessing _to be_ returned values outside of the loop.. `for-loop` is synchronous but `requests` being made inside it are not... `Promise.all` could help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F2 is async. So to callback you need to wait till the requests returns:

```
function(data, callback) {        //f2
    for (var r=0, dataRx=0; r<10; r++){
        var URL = 'url';
        request(URL,function(err, response, body) {
            if(response.statusCode == 200){
                var json = JSON.parse(body);

                x.push(json.name);
                data.rot = x;
            }
            dataRx++;
            if(dataRx === 10) callback(null, data);
        })
    }

},
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working and it's simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are making `asynchronous` requests in a loop and accessing *to be* returned values outside of the loop. `for-loop` is synchronous but `requests` being made inside it are not.

[**`Promise.all`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) could be used,

> *The `Promise.all(iterable)` method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the `iterable` argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.*

```js
function abc(data, callback) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
    var URL = 'url';
    var req = request(URL, function(err, response, body) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);

        x.push(json.name);
        data.rot = x;
      }
    });
    arr.push(req);
  }
  Promise.all(arr).then(function SuccessHandler(arrayOfResults) {
    callback(null, arrayOfResults);
  }, function ErrorHandler(reason) {
    console.log(reason)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but Arun's is easier.

Comment: @BaSic– Pleasure.. I prefer to use `Promise` as testing the value of after each response id `bad` idea.. Also consider that _what if some request from `loop` fails ?_  Your `callback` will never get called. Using `Promise`, you can handle `reject` as well..